# Unable to persist Json object with Spring Data having @OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I have an entity called `Sale`, which has list of objects `SaleData`, I have set up unidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship between these two. Now I ran into a problems when doing CRUD operations on my Sale object.

**`CascadeType` set to `ALL`.**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sale")
public class Sale extends BaseEntity {

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
  private Client client;

  @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}) // <--
  @JoinColumn(name = "sale_id", nullable = false)
  private List<SaleData> saleData = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Save (POST) and Delete works. What's causing problem is when POST-ing for update, my JSON sent from Angular controller looks like that:

```
{"id": 1, "client": {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Test",
    "lastName": "Client"
}, "saleData": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "employee": {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "Herp",
            "lastName": "Derp"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "employee": {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        }
    }
]}
```

Update call from Spring service throws:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: app.sales.SaleData
```

**Service implementation**

```
  @Override
  @Transactional(rollbackFor = SaleNotFoundException.class)
  public Sale update(@NotNull SaleDTO updated) {
    Sale sale = repository.findOne(updated.getId());

    if (sale == null)
      throw new SaleNotFoundException("Sale not found");

    return transformSaleObject(sale, updated);
  }
```

As I understand, cascade ALL doesn't make the sale object Deattached, because in 2nd scenario where I replace the type with any combination of...

```
@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH})
```

.. then **Update** and **Delete** works, but Saving a new object does not. I haven't used Hiberate that much, but maybe anyone knows what's causing this behaviour? Is it the matter of defining relationship wrong way?

**Update:**
The transform method is simply this, but anyway seems like it's all solved for me now :)

```
  private Sale transformSaleObject(Sale sale, SaleDTO dto) {
    sale.setClient(dto.getClient());
    sale.setSaleData(dto.getSaleData());
    sale.setService(dto.getService());
    sale.setHours(dto.getHours());
    sale.setPrice(dto.getPrice());
    sale.setSaleStatus(dto.getSaleStatus());
    sale.setSaleDate(dto.getSaleDate());
    return sale;
  }
```

I changed my update method as follows:

```
  public Sale update(@NotNull SaleDTO updated) {
    Sale sale = repository.findOne(updated.getId());

    if (sale == null)
      throw new SaleNotFoundException("Sale not found");

    transformSaleObject(sale, updated);

    return repository.saveAndFlush(sale);
  }
```

Comment: Your error means that you are trying to persist the same entity(that is with identical id) for second time. Instead of persist you can do update only if your entity is detached(not persistent). As a convenience you can use method `orh.hibernate.Session.saveOrUpdate`. You may find useful [this doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#update(java.lang.Object))

Comment: Spring Data has only `save(entity)` for persisting, and you update by finding the object by Id and changing the values you wish to update, after that you don't call any other methods, but after the end of transaction these changes are commited.

Comment: May be so. Try to remove `@JoinColumn` annotation from @OneToMany relationship to `saleData` collection. Instead put `@JoinColumn(name = "sale_id", nullable = false)` on Sale sale reference inside `SaleData` entity.

Comment: In unidirectional relationship I don't have `Sale` reference in my `SaleData` class. The only reference is in Sale.

Comment: This is not recommended. The better option is to have [bidirectional one-to-many association](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-bidirectional). See what they say about unidirectional one-to-many [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-12m).

Comment: Follow source code of [this project](https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-data-jpa-examples/tree/master/tutorial-part-four). It explains everything about spring data jpa. From model to view.

Comment: His domain models are 'hello world' style, it has zero relationships unfortunately :(

Comment: Yes, but it shows how to use all features of spring repositories. And how to bind them to spring mvc. E.g. your method `Sale update(@NotNull SaleDTO updated)` throws `SaleNotFoundException` but doesn't declare it with `throws` keyword. Therefore your controller won't know what throws `update` and cannot return correct error message to the user.

Comment: That's not the case, this is unchecked exception, I don't intend to catch it in my controller, it will be handled by exception handler if needed by proper json response.

Comment: +1 for using unchecked exceptions, -1 for tagging this with angularjs. You'd have this problem regardless of what front-end you'd use.

Comment: Yes sorry wasn't my intention to bring Angular into it. Anyway I modified my update method to use saveAndFlush from repository which seems to work with ALL cascade, many places point out other solutions where you find the entity you want to edit and set new fields from DTO which will be persisted at the end of transaction. Didn't seem to work here.

Comment: Can you add the transformSaleObject method body too?